# Dynamic Height Element in a sidebar under a Fixed Height Element

Tags: css, height, stylesheet, html

I have a fluid CSS layout for a user application. The goal is that the large content area (white) and the dark blue #notiarea will expand to fill the client desktop. The goal would be to have the #notiarea expand to fill the rest of the user desktop.

The #notiarea and the content div would than have a scrollbar for the content like the image below.

My question is how do I get the darkblue (#notiarea) element to expand to the rest of the application view area height only? **How do I get the #notiarea to be fluid in height under all the fixed height elements**, than I need the ability to use the css tag "overflow:auto;"? I would prefer a css solution but I'll accept a jQuery solution.

[image: example]

**Source code:** Here's a jsfidle for quick experimentation: http://jsfiddle.net/YLZRb/

Comment: Do you want the current source order to be preserved? Or would you mind having #content below the sidebar in the markup?

Comment: Never mind, got it to work as is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo: http://dabblet.com/gist/3768929

I use the *very* useful 'box-sizing: border-box' property to get this result, please read about it here: paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

It is compatible from IE8+, you just need to tweak the layout a wee bit for IE7 and below viz.  you could give the sidebar 'position: absolute' ...it is the best one can do(without too much hassle).

Okay, I've made similar layouts a gazillion times before, and couldn't be more grateful to the box-sizing property. Here's a quick review of the changes:

#sidebar now has a 'padding-top' value equal to the height of #newpostcreator. Then, #newpostcreator is pulled back into place using negative top positioning again with a value equal to its height, in our case: -206px.

Please note, I've also given every element 'position: relative' by using the '*' universal selector. This is pretty useful when you have several absolute positioned elements on a page, so you wouldn't have to specify relative positioning for each respective container. This is mainly a DRY(Don't Repeat Yourself) thing and makes for cleaner code. This also gives every element additional positional control via 'top' 'left' 'right' & 'bottom'.

Also, since #sidebar is 'position: fixed', it is removed from the layout and is positioned relative to the viewport. So we need some blank space for it to rest without interrupting/overlapping the page content. I did this by giving #container a padding-left value equal to sidebar's width. But I saw you'd already done that in your fiddle. i just refined it a lil bit.

Now back to the sidebar, I'd mentioned giving it a 206 px's of padding-top. To understand the logic behind this, you should get to know the box-sizing's role in the layout. Basically, elements with 'border-box' has its padding and border all positioned *inside* the container. So, whatever width you specify the element, adding padding/border will not add its final width/height, it will be contained within. Keep in mind, this does not work with margins.

So, the space left in the sidebar minus 206px's of padding is 100%, which we now give to #notiarea.

That is it pretty much. If you study the code, you'll get a better understanding than what I've been able to provide. Please do check out the link, and remember to add vendor prefixes to box-sizing for older versions of Firefox, Opera and Chrome.

Comment: This is the closets one so far. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Well without explanation (I hope the code speaks for itself) I give you the semantic approach..

http://jsfiddle.net/YLZRb/6/

```
<header>

</header>
<div class="content">
    <aside>
        <section class="post">

        </section>
    </aside>
    <section class="main">

    </section>
</div>
```

and the css

```
html,body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
body {
    background-color: #a3badc;
}
header {
    background-color: #515c6e;
    height:67px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.746094) 0px 5px 5px 0px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.content {
    height: 100%;

}
.content aside {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #032d3b;
    width: 230px;
    height: 100%;
    top: 67px;
    left: 0px;
}
.content aside .post {
    width: 100%;
    height: 220px;
    background-color: #1d779c;
}
.main {
    margin-top: 67px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

​
    ​

​

Comment: While helpful it is not the answer, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Okay!, here it goes.. http://jsfiddle.net/Ghcgr/

Jsfiddle has css problem due its iframe properties and css will work on independent page.. 
make sure you sure `clear`, `float` and `width` [sidebar and ajxpage]

Comment: I am no longer using float's for my sidebar. It wasn't a practical thing, I'm now using margin to pad my page. http://jsfiddle.net/YLZRb/

Comment: It works for fluid designs, have a try with this.. did you try this. And if you use the above fiddle css, then some extra content in `ajxpage` may go down with `notarea` thats a akward momemnt

Comment: No, notarea is not expanding when I resize the page. It stays at a fixed height.

Comment: My css goal is the image. However I want it to resize with the whole thing, and yes I did look at it... nothing was changed. You forgot to save the changes, fork it first!

Comment: Now you check this out http://jsfiddle.net/YLZRb/1/ added `overflow:scroll` css property where you need